# copy master page from one powerpoint presentation to another

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

if i have a powerpoint with a certain set of master pages and backgrounds and i want to conver t an old presentation to do the same, how do i do this?

Comment: You need to tell us which version of PowerPoint you are using if you want detailed step by step on this - 2007 themes work in a very different way to older 2000 / 2003 way of doing things, so to get the shortest option we need to know which instructions you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [Apply multiple slide masters to a new or existing presentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/HA102513531033.aspx) for PowerPoint 2007 (will probably work in principle for earlier versions but with different user interface):

> **Copy and paste a slide master from one presentation to another**
>
> 1. Open both the presentation that contains the slide master that you
>      want to copy and the presentation that
>      you will paste the slide master to.
> 2. In the presentation that contains the slide master that you want to
>      copy, on the View menu, in the
>      Presentation Views group, click Slide
>      Master.
> 3. In the slide thumbnail pane, right-click the slide master that you
>      want to copy, and then click
>      Copy.
> 4. On the View tab, in the Window group, click Switch Windows, and then
>      select the presentation that you want
>      to paste the slide master to.
> 5. In the presentation that you want to paste the slide master to, on the
>      View menu, in the Presentation Views
>      group, click Slide Master.
> 6. In the slide thumbnail pane, to click the location where you want the
>      slide master to reside, do one of the
>      following:
>     a. If the destination
>      presentation contains a blank slide
>      master, right-click the blank slide
>      master, and then click Paste.
>     b.
>      If the destination presentation
>      contains one or more customized slide
>      masters, scroll to the bottom where
>      the last slide layout resides,
>      right-click below it, and then click
>      Paste.
> 7. To copy and paste additional slide masters, follow steps 1 through 6.
> 8. On the Slide Master tab, in the Close group, click Close Master View.